# Java execute multiple console commands on loaded program

Tags: java, console, command, runtime, execute

I want to load a program from the console and then execute commands on it later on. The loading works fine, but how can I execute commands on the loaded program without starting it every time I want to use it?

For example:
./randomapp
command1
command2

But on Java, I have to usw ./randomapp command1 every time I want to execute something on it, so the program doesn't stay loaded.

Comment: If you can execute a command that's passed as a command line argument you can alsa read a command from standard input/Console and execute it. Where is the problem?

Comment: I want to use a runtime to load a program using ./startprogram. Then I want to use another runtime somewhere later on to execute a programs command from the new runtime. But the problem is, the program is no longer loaded from another runtime, like it would be when I start it from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing anything about your Java program or the app you'd like to execute and feed with commands, this is a shot in the dark. Also, all error handling is omitted. I'm using tee for the program to be run because it's convenient.

```
public class Command {
    private static OutputStream os;
    private static OutputStreamWriter osw;
    private static Process process;
    public static void start(){
        try { 
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "/usr/bin/tee", "x.dat" );
            process = pb.start();
            os = process.getOutputStream();
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter( os );
        } catch( Exception e ){
            // error handling
        } catch( Error e ){
            // error handling
        }
    }

    public static void terminate() throws Exception {
        process.waitFor();
    }

    public static void command( String str ) throws Exception {
        String cmd = str + System.lineSeparator();
        osw.write( cmd, 0, cmd.length() );
        osw.flush();
    }
```

I've tested this using:

```
Command.start();
Command.command( "line 1" );
Thread.sleep( 2000 );
Command.command( "line 2" );
Thread.sleep( 2000 );
Command.command( "line 3" );
Command.terminate();
```

The lines can be found on x.dat.

Comment: How can I parse the return of the console?

Comment: You can obtain the process.getInputStream() delivering the application's standard output. And you can start or continue reading this after writing another command. BUT: do you know how many lines to expect?